# Ways to sum a series. Questions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am reading a journal on ways to sum a series and the author considers the following:

Suppose one wants to sum the alternating series $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{k} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + ...$

Consider the closely related power series $f(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}z^k = z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{3} + \frac{z^4}{4} + ...$

The general problem of evaluating $f$ is at first glance, much harder than our original problem, which only concerns $-f(-1)$. But if we differeniate $f(z)$ we get

$f'(z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}z^{k-1} = 1 + z + z^2 + ...$

Since this is a geometric series, $f'(z) = \displaystyle\frac{1}{(1-z)}$

Then $f(z) = \displaystyle\int \frac{1}{(1-z)} dz = -\ln(1-z) + C$.

We know from the defintion that $f(0) = 0$. Consequently, $C = 0$ and so $f(z) = -\ln(1-z)$. It follows that $-f(-1) = \ln 2$.

I have a couple questions about this problem.

He considers a closely related power series that is not alternating and says we are only concerned with $-f(-1)$. Why did he pick a series that is not alternating and where is $-f(-1)$ coming from? Why are we evaluating $-f(-1)$ at the end?

After obtaining an answer from the integral he says it follows from the definition that $f(0) = 0$. Is he just implying that $-\ln(1-0) = 0$? If so why would that matter?

Lastly how does he know that $C = 0$?

Other then my questions its a pretty cool concept! The help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(0)=0+\frac{0^2}{2}+\frac{0^3}{3}+\dots=0\tag{1}$$
$$f(0)=-\ln(1-0)+C\stackrel{(1)}{=}0 \iff -\ln 1+C=0 \iff C=\ln 1=0$$

$-f(-1)$ is the above alternate series.

Comment: Why do we want to evaluate $f$ at zero though? Whats the reasoning? And I am still not sure I see what $-f(-1)$ has to do with the alternating series. Maybe an example?

Comment: @NickFreeman We decide to evaluate $f$ at $0$ because it doesn't require to evaluate the sum with the formula, we can do it by directly observing the sum. As for $-f(-1)$ try replacing $z$ with $-1$ at the first formula($f(z)=z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\dots$), then change all the signs(that's multiplying the sum by $-1$). Before changing the signs, evaluate all the powers first.

Comment: Okay $-f(-1)$ makes sense to me. I wasn't sure what you were talking about for why $f$ is $0$. Thanks for the help. I do appreciate. Just want to make sure I know whats going on.

Comment: @NickFreeman if I was of help you can consider upvoting and accepting the answer. People tend to answer less your questions if you do neither.

Comment: I am still a little unsure on the whole reason $f$ is taken to be $0$. Wasn't sure what you were saying. If you could explain one more time I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You have to find a value for a particular $x$, so after you know the value you can equate that formula with the value and get an equation with 1 unknown(your $C$). $x=0$ is the easiest one(if you choose another you'll have to evaluate the sum somehow without the formula for that value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18224/discussion-between-nick-freeman-and-userx).